# What are some access control installation mistakes?

Tags: control, wiring

We are experiencing unstable data transmission from reader to controller.
This is the scenario.
Card EPC is c9895443 in binary:

1100 1001 1000 1001 0101 0100 0100 0011

But what the controller outputs are inconsistent.

1110 0100 1100 0100 1010 1000 1000 111 - 31 bit

1110 0100 0100 0100 1000 0100 0100 0011 1 - 33 bit

1110 0100 1100 0000 1010 1010 0010 0001 - 32 bit

1110 0000 1100 0100 1010 1010 0100 0011 - 32 bit

Note. The reader is set to wiegand 34.

Can anyone give me some possible reason why are these happening?

Thanks. :D

Comment: Do you have Parity? is std format  32 data bits +2 parity with  Even parity bit at start  then Odd parity bit at end for 34 bits?  it seems  the word sync is not working

Comment: what word sync? the parity were auto generated.

Comment: Where might be the problem? the reader or the controller?

Comment: If the reader strips off parity yet does not report a read error and sends bits that result in underflow or overflow of data bits, then I would say it is the reader. But if the reader is supposed to pass on parity for the controller to verify, then it is the Controller.  I have no experience with this wand.

Answer (score 1):

It was all a grounding issue. We forgot to connect the ground wire of the reader to the controller. Our mistakes XD